# Basic modal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a basic modal which shall open and display the content. I will give now my best to describe how it looks since I cannot add images.

So I have an image slider, where the heading is changing depending on which img is currently displayed. When you click onto the current image then a modal shall open.

The modal has on the left-hand side a ul where are all the headings of the img slider, so the user can within the modal change the modal´s content.

What I now want is when the user is clicking on one image in the slide-show that the matching content is opening and not just the first of the modal content list. (Modal Content is stored in a collection)

I imagine it is quite confusing to read this, so if anyone knows where I could post screenshots I would do so.

So here my problem:

```
const displayContent = () => {
  headingString = currentHeading.textContent.toUpperCase();
  modalContentsCollection = modals[index].childNodes[1].children;
  choices = modalContentsCollection[0].querySelectorAll('li a');
  let compareArray = [];
  choices.forEach(element => {
    compareArray.push(element.textContent.toUpperCase().trim());
  });
  let b = false;
  console.log(compareArray);
  console.log(headingString);
  let c = 0
  while (!b && c < compareArray.length)  {
    console.log(compareArray[c]);
    console.log(c);
    if (headingString == compareArray[c]) {
      console.log(modalContentsCollection[c]);
      console.log(c);    
      modalContentsCollection[c].classList.toggle('show-toggle');
      console.log(modalContentsCollection[c]);
      b = true;
    c++;
  }
  modalContentsCollection[0].classList.toggle('show-toggle');
};
```

I wrote a function that compares the current heading to an array which returns me the index, so I know which modal content needs to be opened. So the problem is that `modalContentsCollection[c].classList.toggle('show-toggle');` is not working, but without my loop it is. I wrote at the end `modalContentsCollection[0].classList.toggle('show-toggle');` as fall back if none heading is matching.

I posted pictures here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub48f.jpg
So when I click on "the image while Das Haus" is displayed the modal should show the content of "Das Haus", but if I click on "Wintersport the content of "Wintersport" should be displayed etc.

Comment: You can upload the image to a third party site like [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and share the link.

Comment: Does the code throw an error?

Comment: @akshithDayanand No sorry it does not throw any errors.

Comment: @AdityaPrakash I#ll have a look. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I added images.

Comment: @Snake_py Put the code on https://jsfiddle.net/ then I'll fix it for you. Replace the `img` `href` with `https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x200` instead of your images.

Comment: I just wanna know @LoiNguyenHuynh if the function I wrote seems right? Then I#ll debug it myself.

Comment: @Snake_py I don't have the exact HTML markup so I'm not sure, but the code you wrote looks too much `C style`, like you used `while` loop and `if` too much like the `C style` way, like "from scratch" style. the `compareArray ... choices.forEach ... compareArray.push` can be replaced with `.map()`. Not sure if your code functions correctly but there're rooms to refactor.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Thank you very much for the hints. It is my first project and the first time I use JS. I have not finished learning the core functions, yet. So I am pretty sure there are a lot of improvements to make. But I don't want to refactor it to a point that I don't understand my own project :D I'll try it myself and if I come not further I'll contact you.

Comment: Try solving small challanges js algorithm via `HackerRank` or other coding challanges page. Learn at least the basic higher order functions like `.map()`, `reduce()`, `.forEach()`,... it'll make you to be more productive in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, I know you are right. But I'll help my mum with this project and I had no time to learn everything. JS is not the first language I learned, it is the 3rd. So I'll just bring it to run then I can make it pretty and refactor after I learned more about the language.

Comment: Yo So I rewrote my function and now it is working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I went biking for and ate something. So with fresh head I rewrote above function to

```
const displayContent = () => {
  console.log('displayContent');
  let headingString = currentHeading.textContent.toUpperCase();
  let modalContentsCollection = modals[index].childNodes[1].children;
  let choices = modalContentsCollection[0].querySelectorAll('li a');
  let compareArray = [];
  choices.forEach(element => {
    compareArray.push(element.textContent.toUpperCase().trim());
  });
  let i = 0;
  let bool = false;
  compareArray.forEach(element => {
    if (element === headingString) {
      modalContentsCollection[i].classList.toggle('show-toggle');
      bool = true;
      return;
    }
    i++;
  });
  if (!bool) {
    modalContentsCollection[0].classList.toggle('show-toggle');
  }
};
```

Perhaps someone can tell me why this one is working but the above on is not.

Anyway, thanks to all the people who were interested in helping. By the end of this project, I will post the source code for a review and tips, so I can learn. I guess this should be done on exchangeoverflow?

Comment: If you want a review of working code that you wrote yourself, check out the help center of [codereview.se] to see if your question is on topic there.